# Another way instead of escaping regex patterns?

Tags: ruby, regex

Usually when my regex patterns look like this:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/
```

Then i have to escape it like this:

```
string.match(/http:\/\/www\.microsoft\.com\//)
```

Is there another way instead of escaping it like that?

I want to be able to just use it like this http://www.microsoft.com, cause I don't want to escape all the special characters in all my patterns.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.quote('http://www.microsoft.com/'))
```

[`Regexp.quote`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001194) simply escapes any characters that have special regexp meaning; it takes and returns a string.  Note that `.` is also special.  After quoting, you can append to the regexp as needed before passing to the constructor.  A simple example:

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.quote('http://www.microsoft.com/') + '(.*)')
```

This adds a capturing group for the rest of the path.

Comment: Of course this works too: `string.match(/#{Regexp.quote('http://www.microsoft.com/')}/)`

Comment: replacing all "CURRENT_YEAR" tokens with a four digit year capture group:
`Regexp.new( input_string.split("CURRENT_YEAR").map { |p| Regexp.quote(p) }.join("(\\d{4})") )`

Comment: Given that, shouldn't this return success?

puts "Success" if Regexp.new(Regexp.quote('.')).match('A')

Answer (score 10):

You can also use arbitrary delimiters in Ruby for regular expressions by using %r and defining a character before the regular expression, for example:

```
%r!http://www.microsoft.com/!
```

Comment: While this helps for avoiding escaping `/` characters, it doesn't help for things like parentheses, brackets, and other special characters.

Answer (score 8):

`Regexp.quote` or `Regexp.escape` can be used to automatically escape things for you:

https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape

The result can be passed to `Regexp.new` to create a Regexp object, and then you can call the object's `.match` method and pass it the string to match against (the opposite order from `string.match(/regex/)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use single quotes for escaping.

```
string.match('http://www.microsoft.com/')
```

you can also use `%q{}` if you need single quotes in the text itself. If you need to have variables extrapolated inside the string, then use `%Q{}`. That's equivalent to double quotes `"`.
If the string contains regex expressions (eg: `.*?()[]^$`) that you want extrapolated, use // or %r{}

Answer (score -1):

For convenience I just define

```
def regexcape(s)
  Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(s))
end
```